# Set the content of a new row Datagrid

Tags: wpf, database

I have a DataGrid showing some databases having quite some columns.
I would like that, when the user edit a new row, some values are set automatically.
With the windows form DataGrid that would be easy, since there's RowsAdded event handler.
But how could i handle this with the wpf DataGrid ??
Edit : my DataGrid is bound in Xaml to a public property which is an ITable. When user select a table in a ComboBox, the property is updated with corresponding table.
Yes there's autogenerating column, and the way the user can enter a new row is to edit the last blank row (default behaviour).

Comment: How exactly are you adding a new row? Are your grid columns auto-generated? If not, what are they bound to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i got it.
When a DataTable is bound to a DataGrid, a CollectionView is created in order to see it. You can get it by using the (static/shared) CollectionView.GetDefaultView(ThePropertyThatIsBound) method.
Since it implements ICollectionChanged, you can add an event handler to the CollectionChangedEvent.

In the CollectionChanged event handler, if you have a new item (e.NewItems.Count>0) you must check it against System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder and if it is not a place holder, then it is a brand new item, for wich i can set all default values.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the LoadingRow event. Try something like this:

```
private void myDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject myObject = e.Row.Item as MyObject;
    if (myObject != null)
    {
        myObject.PropertyOne = "test";
        myObject.PropertyTwo = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tahnk you this may be a start, but the issue is that LoadingRow is triggered for any row : all rows containing valid data as well as the new row just built for the user when he edits the last row. So how could i know this is a 'new' row ? Obviously i could test if all object values are the default values, but it seems like a hack...

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `CollectionViewSource` to your `DataGrid` then listen to the `CollectionChanged` event as following :

```
..
public CollectionViewSource ViewSource { get; set; }
..
this.ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
this.ViewSource.Source = new List<YourObjectType>();
this.ViewSource.View.CollectionChanged += View_CollectionChanged;

..

private void View_CollectionChanged(object sender,System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems.Count > 0)
    {
        YourObjectType myObject = e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count-1] as YourObjectType;
        if (myObject != null)
        {
            myObject.Property        = TheValueYouWant;
            ..
        }
    }
}
..
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource.View}" ../>
```

Comment: This sets the values of all items of `myObject`. What is the way to set the values only for the new Item in DataGrid? (maybe check if it is `NewItemPlaceholder`)