# WPF: How do I set different default null values in a DataGrid if a new row is added?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is bound to a `DataTable` that is filled by an `SqlDataAdapter`, which fills it with an unspecified table, and I therefore have no way of knowing how the structure in the table is. I've set the `TargetNullValue` to `NULL`, and the cells that contains a null-value from the database shows `NULL` in the `DataGrid`, which is perfect.

However... when I want to add a new row using `DataGrid`'s `CanUserAddRow`, the default values are all "NULL", and I want them to be empty.

I am able to change cells that expect the type of `string` to show up empty, but in the cells that expect `int`'s for example, it can't contain an empty string, or an `int` that is `NULL`. If I want it to be `NULL`, it has to be `DBNull` instead, which gives me "NULL" in the cell, which doesn't make any difference.

Any one with an idea how to overcome this issue of mine?

Thanks in advance.

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Table" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          CanUserAddRows="true"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_Table_AutoGeneratingColumn"
          InitializingNewItem="dataGrid_Table_InitializingNewItem"/>
```

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void dataGrid_Table_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,
    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // Make all columns nullable
    ((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding.TargetNullValue = "NULL";
}
private void dataGrid_Table_InitializingNewItem(object sender,
    InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.NewItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < drv.Row.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        DataColumn col = drv.Row.Table.Columns[i];
        if (col.DataType.ToString() == "System.String")
        {
            drv.Row[i] = "";
        }
        else if (col.DataType.ToString() == "System.Int32")
        {
            // Set cells that expect an int to show up empty
        }
    }
}
```

**Method for filling the `DataTable` and binding it to the `DataGrid`**

```
internal void FillDataGrid(User user, MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    dt = new DataTable();    
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Name, con))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            mainWindow.dataGrid_Table.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this link from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485664/set-the-content-of-a-new-row-datagrid) is helpful to you or not.

Comment: @sagar I'm afraid it isn't. Thanks a bunch for trying to help, though!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, where a `SqlDataAdapter` was populating a `DataGrid`. I needed `Boolean` fields to be shown on the `DataGrid`, but it seems that the default values are always NULL for every column value in the row. The Boolean `NULL` value in the UI looks like a checked box, which misrepresents what the value actually is.

I found a solution that looks a little messy but it get the job done.

You want to add the `LoadingRow` option to the `DataGrid` XAML

```
<DataGrid ... LoadingRow="myDataGrid_LoadingRow"/>
```

This will appear sometime during the creation of the row.  Whether or not this is a new line. So if you have a `DataGrid` with 100 rows, it will call this function 100 times as each row is loaded. So I did a few things here:

(1) Made sure that the `e.Row.Item` is a `DataRowView` Object to avoid an error throw.

(2) Checking to see if the row is being created by using `.IsNew`, avoiding all rows from the original list of rows.

(3) As you cast the object as `System.Data.DataRowView` you will be able to pull up the future values of that row. I have static columns, so that 11 and 10 are my columns. I need to set the values for the new rows to false, but you could enter any values you want (if you want them to be empty use `""`).

```
private void myDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender,
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Item is System.Data.DataRowView)
    {
        if (((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.Item).IsNew)
        {
            ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.Item)[11] = false;
            ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.Item)[10] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `LoadingRow` but I couldn't work it out correctly.